# FSDataInputStream ClassNotFoundException in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to spark application programming, and therefore struggling here with this basic one..

I have scala ide and attached relevant jar files from the latest hadoop and spark distributions.  There is just one basic scala object that i am working with - 
hadoop - 2.7
spark - 2.0.0

I have attempted this with both scenarios, when hadoop processes are running on my laptop and also when they are not running.. its the same behaviour. Btw, spark shell is not complaining of anything

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SparkAppTest {
  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark test")
    conf.setMaster("spark://master:7077")
    conf.setSparkHome("/hadoop/spark")
    conf.set("spark.driver.host","localhost")

  }
}
```

When I am trying to "run" this using eclipse -> run as scala app this is failing with the following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.loadFromSystemProperties(SparkConf.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:55)
    at SparkAppTest$.main(SparkAppTest.scala:6)
    at SparkAppTest.main(SparkAppTest.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Show us your build.sbt/pom.xml

Comment: You seem to be missing the a hadoop library dependency